# How to add Else to the select from where SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement

I want to add to this code an `ELSE profil_code='abc_all'`

```
SELECT abc.contact_id
FROM   t_sup_supplier s 
INNER JOIN t_bas_address adr ON adr.adr_id=s.adr_id_office
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT l.contact_id
    FROM t_usr_login l
    INNER JOIN t_usr_login_profil LP ON lp.login_name=l.login_name
    WHERE profil_code=CONCAT('abc_', adr.country_code)
) abc
WHERE s.sup_id=@x_id
```

How can I do it?

So if the last part `profil_code=CONCAT('abc_', adr.country_code)` was not found, it should take `profil_code='abc_all'`

Comment: Did you mean to have a `TOP 1` with that APPLY? Otherwise there's no advantage here over using a JOIN, and it would also simplify an alternate way I could interpret your question that would lead to a different answer from what I provided.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know which dbms is using the software

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE profil_code= COALESCE( CONCAT('abc_', adr.country_code), 'abc_all')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a COALESCE function in the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE profil_code = COALESCE(
    CONCAT('abc_', adr.country_code), 
    'abc_all'
)
```

Or use a OR operator:

```
WHERE 
    (profil_code=CONCAT('abc_', adr.country_code) or profil_code = 'abc_all')
```

Comment: THe first code is not working unfortionattely. I get an error. The second code is working but here I am getting always both. But I need only 'abc_all' if the other was not found

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
profil_code=CONCAT('abc_', adr.country_code) or profil_code='abc_all'
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of Fabio's answer.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. It is working but i need instead OR an ELSE. Because only if ('abc_', adr.country_code) is NOT availible, then only take profil_code='abc_all'

Answer (score 0):

the provided solutuions are working but not as I was expecting. now both are triggered.
I need only if ('abc_', adr.country_code) was not found, then only take profil_code='abc_all'. But if the ('abc_', adr.country_code) was found then NOT take profil_code='abc_all

Comment: This is not an answer. you can update your question with this information

Answer (score 0):

So I tried as following:

```
SELECT abc.contact_id
FROM   t_sup_supplier s 
INNER JOIN t_bas_address adr ON adr.adr_id=s.adr_id_office
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT l.contact_id
    FROM t_usr_login l
    INNER JOIN t_usr_login_profil LP ON lp.login_name=l.login_name
    WHERE profil_code= COALESCE( CONCAT('abc_', adr.country_code), 'abc_all')
) abc
WHERE s.sup_id=@x_id
```

--> Here it is now showing the 'abc_all' but it is existing in the table

```
SELECT abc.contact_id
FROM   t_sup_supplier s 
INNER JOIN t_bas_address adr ON adr.adr_id=s.adr_id_office
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT l.contact_id
    FROM t_usr_login l
    INNER JOIN t_usr_login_profil LP ON lp.login_name=l.login_name
    WHERE (profil_code=CONCAT('abc_', adr.country_code) or profil_code = 'abc_all')
) abc
WHERE s.sup_id=@x_id
```

--> Here it is working but only partly. Because if both values are existing it is also showing me both. I need only the first value. If first not exist only then the second.